# Pandas dataframe can't plot x values from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to read yearly data into a Pandas dataframe from a CSV file, but it's not reading the years correctly. I think the problem is that I have to transpose the rows and columns.

Here's a simplified example that shows the problem.

```
from io import StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

# This is what I wish I had.
csv_source1 = StringIO("""\
year,Apples,Bananas,Cherries
1990,1,2,3
1997,1,4,9
1999,1,8,27
""")
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_source1, index_col=0)
df1.index.names = ['Year']
df1.columns.names = ['fruit']

# This is what I actually have.
csv_source2 = StringIO("""\
fruit,1990,1997,1999
Apples,1,1,1
Bananas,2,4,8
Cherries,3,9,27
""")
# So I transpose it.
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_source2, index_col=0).T
df2.index.names = ['Year']

sn.set()
ax = plt.subplot(211)
df1.plot(ax=ax)

ax = plt.subplot(212)
df2.plot(ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That generates this pair of plots:

[image: good and bad plots]

I want to plot the price of each fruit over the years, but the data I'm reading has a row for each fruit, and a column for each year. The first plot shows what happens when I plot the data I wish I had. The second plot shows what happens when I plot the data I have after doing the transpose.

Why are the years not shown on the second plot's x axis? The data is evenly spaced, so is it not even reading the year data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the year data is being read in as strings when it's in the header row, and then it can't be used as data for the x axis. To convert the years to integers, convert the columns before doing the transpose.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_source2, index_col=0)
df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(int)
df2 = df2.T
```

Here's the full script with the change.

```
from io import StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn

# This is what I wish I had.
csv_source1 = StringIO("""\
year,Apples,Bananas,Cherries
1990,1,2,3
1997,1,4,9
1999,1,8,27
""")
df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_source1, index_col=0)
df1.index.names = ['Year']
df1.columns.names = ['fruit']

# This is what I actually have.
csv_source2 = StringIO("""\
fruit,1990,1997,1999
Apples,1,1,1
Bananas,2,4,8
Cherries,3,9,27
""")
# So I convert the years to integers and transpose it.
df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_source2, index_col=0)
df2.columns = df2.columns.astype(int)
df2 = df2.T
df2.index.names = ['Year']

sn.set()
ax = plt.subplot(211)
df1.plot(ax=ax)

ax = plt.subplot(212)
df2.plot(ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And the fixed plot makes them both the same.

[image: fixed plots]